# Flutter Image_Picker crash iOS app when open Camera

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

everything works perfect in Android when I open gallery or Camera, but when I try on iOS (emulator and real device) gallery works perfect but as soon as I press the Camera option the app crash without console logs only "Lost connection to device"

```
 // get image File camera
 _getFromCamera(BuildContext context) async {
   XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
     source: ImageSource.camera,
     maxWidth: 1800,
     maxHeight: 1800,
   );
   File rotatedImage =
       await FlutterExifRotation.rotateAndSaveImage(path: pickedFile!.path);
   if (pickedFile != null) {
     image = rotatedImage;
     //File(pickedFile.path);
     final userId = widget.id;
     widget.bloc.uploadProfilePicture(image, userId);
   }
 }

Then I called the function in a Icon button

TextButton.icon(
                     icon: Icon(
                       Icons.photo_camera,
                       color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                     ),
                     label: Text(
                       AppLocalization.of(context)!
                           .getTranslatedValues("cameraLbl")!,
                       style: TextStyle(
                           color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                     ),
                     onPressed: () {
                       _getFromCamera(context);
                       Navigator.of(context).pop();
                     },
                   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add additional permissions inside the info.plist file

Add these entries inside it :

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs PhotoLib access</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs camera access</string>
```

To add permissions in flutter application, you need to add permissions in both android manifest and info.plist file.

Also you can use any string inside the string tag , and that string would be shown to the user as why the user needs to give permission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the permission keys inside the info.plist file (located in {app_folder}/ios/Runner/Info.plist

[Here is the info.plist file located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpXDp.png)

Open it and place this:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs PhotoLib access</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs camera access</string>
```

inside

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
```

and

```
    </dict>
</plist>
```

so the info.plist File will look like this:

```
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <!-- Add it here -->
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Needs PhotoLib access</string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Needs camera access</string>
        <!-- End of the added permissions -->
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
```

this will display the permission window for the camera and gallery

Hint: Hot reload is not enougth! Press "Stop Debugging" and "Start Debugging"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NehilKoshiya better like this?
if not can you explain me what I need to add?